# JSP passing arrays as parameters adds square brackets to first and last element

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm developing a spring mvc3 app and encountered the following situation:

1. I return through a ModelAndView object 2 items : 
   jobs = ArrayList
   departments = ArrayList into Page1.jsp
2. When I print the objects in Page1 i get :

for all of them:

```
${jobs} -> [ADMIN, CLERK, DEPARTMENT_MANANGER, DIVISION_MANAGER]
```

and individually I get them well, each one on a line

```
<c:forEach items="${jobs}" var="job">
    <h6>${job}</h6>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is when I include page2.jsp and send those arrays as parameters.

```
<jsp:include page="page2.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="jobs" value="${jobs}" />
    <jsp:param name="departments" value="${departments}" />
</jsp:include>
```

and try to print those elements again I get brackets in the first and last elements. (I've accessed the arrays correctly with param.jobs .. )

for all of them : [ADMIN, CLERK, DEPARTMENT_MANANGER, DIVISION_MANAGER]
each one individually:

```
[ADMIN
CLERK
DEPARTMENT_MANANGER
DIVISION_MANAGER]
```

Does anybody know why this happens and how I can avoid that?

Later edit:

Also, when I iterate through the departments which are supposed to be objects in page2.jsp and try to print their name ($dept.name, which in page1.jsp works fine) i get :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String
```

which is a clear indicator that they are passed as Strings.

How can I have them as Objects as in page1.jsp?

Thanks :)

---

I've found some sort of workaround..

```
<c:set var="allJobs" value="${jobs}" scope="request" />
```

and then I can access them as ${allJobs}

Not sure if this is the most orthodox way though..

Comment: sry it was my mistake in my answer . i posted without formatting . Glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass Strings as request parameters, but you can set any kind of object as request attributes. Request scope (not page scope) beans should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the values using jstl,

```
<c:set var="type1" value="${jobs}" />

    <jsp:include page="index.html">
        <jsp:param name="jobs" value="${type1}" />
    </jsp:include>
```

Hope this helps!!